# Problem with cmake + em

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use cmake for some source files that I have which I then need to launch as ros nodes.  I have src folder for my source code of the ros packages and a build-prefix folder which is my cmake_install_prefix ( in this case /root/openrobots is my  cmake_install_prefix ). When I run ccmake .. in  the build folder which is inside my src/ros_package folder, this is what I get:

```
 CMake Error at
 /root/openrobots/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
   execute_process(/root/src/ranger_ros/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
   "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
   "/root/src/ranger_ros/build/catkin_generated/pkg.develspace.context.pc.py"
   "-o" "/root/src/ranger_ros/build/devel/lib/pkgconfig/ranger_ros.pc"
   "/root/openrobots/share/catkin/cmake/em/pkg.pc.em") returned error code 2
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   /root/openrobots/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:23
 (safe_execute_process)
   /root/openrobots/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:355 (em_expand)
   /root/openrobots/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98
 (_catkin_package)
   CMakeLists.txt:15 (catkin_package)
```

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193809/problem-with-cmake-+-em/) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-30**:
Try running the command printed in `execute_process()` manually. May be that gives you more information than just error code 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently empy was missing and after installing itthis issue was resolved. However I would still get some errors because of boost system libraries. I then had to install two different version of  libboost-system1.40 and libboost-system1.56 and I was able to make!

---

Originally posted by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) with karma: 88 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1